# Why is the complexity of heap Delete element equal to O(logn) and Build is O(n)?

Tags: heap, complexity-theory, analysis

I am having trouble with understanding complexity in general, can you please explain why is Delete complexity in heap equal to O(log n) and why is Build O(n)? ( I assume insertion  with complexity O(1) refers only to the adding of the element, without the place switching).
Isn't the element that we add at the bottom suppose to move all the way up in the worst case? Therefore ( even though i don't understand why it is log n ) , shouldn't the Build be O(log n) as well?

Comment: think about the find the right place, copy all elements according to the structure vs clean up and move elements upside

Comment: @gkhaos isn't the building doing the same thing?Moving the element all the way up in the worst case, therefore going up on one branch? If it makes sense.

Comment: maybe you can refer to the source you found that heap build is slower than delete. On short google search I found this Question: [Why deallocating heap memory is much slower than allocating it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38030504/why-deallocating-heap-memory-is-much-slower-than-allocating-it)

Answer (score 1):

Constructing a heap from an array is O(n) because it uses the `build_heap` algorithm to rearrange the array in place. That's fundamentally different from doing `n` insert operations that are O(log n) each in the worst case. Building a heap by repeated insertion is O(n log n).

Removing the highest priority item uses this algorithm:

```
move the last item in the heap to the root
decrease the count by 1
starting at the new root node, move it down the heap to its proper place:
while the node is larger than either of its children
    swap the node with its smallest child
```

This is O(log n) because moving the node down the heap can potentially require O(log n) swaps.

See [how to build heap tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52600839/56778) for an explanation of the `build_heap` algorithm.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49781979/56778 for an explanation of how `build_heap` is O(n).